# Create a column using select and add data to it depending on a condition?

Tags: sql-server

I'm asked to select some columns from a table. One of which does not exist in the table. This column is called `PayComment` and I need to use a conditional to check if there is data in another separate column inside that table. If there is `PayComment` will say 'Yes' If there isn't it will say 'no'.

I'm confused on how to do this because I've only ever created a column using an alias(`[OldColumn] AS [NewColumn]`) or declared it as a variable and INSERT it into the table. However I have to create this column/use a conditional to determine what's inside it, while keeping it in the select statement whilst I grab the other existing columns.

I know this is wrong but this is what I'm imagining

```
CREATE PROC spPayIncreaseListing
AS
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, CONVERT(varchar, HireDate, 1) AS HireDate, PayRate, 
    CONVERT(varchar, StartDate, 1) AS PayRateStartDate, CONVERT(varchar, EndDate, 1) AS PayRateEndDate, 
    PayComment AS IF Work.COLA > 0
                        PayComment = 'Yes';
                  ELSE  
                        PayComment = 'NO';
```

[image]

Comment: You want a [case expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Just edited it now

Comment: @DaleK Here's what I'm expecting

Comment: The 'PayComment' column needs to be created

Comment: @Dale Im going to try the CASE expression

Comment: How? Thats why we need to see the sample starting data to see what you are using to calculate that. Also please put data in as formatted text, not as an image.

Comment: Your question says you want "Yes" or "No" your expected results show various different strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you are asking for this would be the [`case` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you would need:

```
CREATE PROC spPayIncreaseListing
AS
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, CONVERT(varchar, HireDate, 1) AS HireDate, PayRate, 
    CONVERT(varchar, StartDate, 1) AS PayRateStartDate, CONVERT(varchar, EndDate, 1) AS PayRateEndDate, 
    CASE WHEN Work.COLA > 0 THEN 'Yes' else 'No' END AS PayComment
```

Comment: case **expression** not statement